# Как дозаписать в массив POST данные к существующим записям input[type="file"]

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Есть такой HTML код со вставками PHP

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form_'.$this->post_id_gallery.'" method="post" name="    form">
    <input type="hidden" value='.$this->post_id_gallery.' id="gallaryid_'.$this->post_id_gallery.'">
    <div class="fooupload_button_add"><input type="file" class="inputfile" id="file_'.$this->    post_id_gallery.'" accept="image/*" name="file[]" multiple="false" onclick="createImgPreview(form_'    .$this->post_id_gallery.', file_'.$this->post_id_gallery.')"/>
        <label for="file_'.$this->post_id_gallery.'">
            <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add files
        </label>
        <div class="status status_'.$this->post_id_gallery.' '.$status.'" style="background-color: '    .$color_bg.'">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="preview-area"></div>
    <div class="fooupload_button">
        <button type="button" class="reset" onclick="resetImgPreview(form_'.$this->post_id_gallery.', file_'    .$this->post_id_gallery.')"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>Delete</button>
        <span class="icon-submit">
            <i class="fa fa-upload"></i>
            <input id="submit" name="submit_'.$this->post_id_gallery.'" type="submit" value="Upload" />
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Нужно чтобы при повторном нажатии на input[type="file"] и выборе файла, предыдущие данные файлов в массиве $_FILES не стирались, а происходила дозапись.

Данная логика нужна для того, чтобы пользователь, в случае когда он выбрал не все нужные ему файлы, мог добавить еще, через этот же input. Каким образом это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать JS для добавления еще одного input c name="file[1]" и так сколько угодно(или до ограничения) файлов можно прикрепить.

Comment: Я примерно так и поступил, только создал еще один `input[type=hidden]`, и показывал его после первого добавления файлов. Больше, как оказалось, мне не нужно, так как произошли изменения в тз и появилось огранечение на количество итераций добавления. Все равно спасибо, что обралили внимание на мой вопрос.